# iOS - Find white pixels/area enclosed by a black curve and create path

Tags: ios, swift, path, draw, shapes

Using Swift methods **touchBegan, touchMoved** and **touchEnded** I save the touch points and than I draw a line using **UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()** with methods **beginPath(), move(to: Point), addLine(to: Point) and strokePath()**. 
This line is repeated on 4 quadrants plus their negative values, therefore 8 lines are drawn.

Here is an example: 
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsA3y.png)

I save this drawing as an Image when the user taps the tick (Done green button at top-right) for later manipulations.

I wonder if it's possible to create e closed path/shape with white pixels enclosed by the black lines. I want to fill the white area with custom color when the user touches inside it.

The shape is created by user input and I have no idea how it would look like.

Would be thankful to whoever finds the time to give it's contribute.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is the "Flood Fill" algorithm, please see the [article](https://ilearnios.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/scanline-flood-fill-algorithm-with-or-without-tolerance-in-objective-c/).